# Strange issue in vim, code not updating

Tags: vim, editing

I have been using my Vim setup for quite some time now, but all of a sudden the saving of code does not update the code. I use [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) for browsing files.

Opening a file normally, i.e. as Vim from console doesnt seem to give problems.

But when I open a file through FuzzyFinder it shows the old code without changes. 
However, opening it through a other editor (or without the plugin) or doing `git diff` shows the changes.

Is it some problem caused by Git, a bug in the plugin, or maybe a cache issue?

Comment: What if you edit and save on the "old code"? Next time when you open the file through Fuzzy finder, which version you see?

Comment: I'd like to see if I can reproduce the problem. What are the filenames in the set and what's the the fuzzy filter mask you're using? I'm also assuming you're using this version of FuzzyFinder? http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984 Finally what version of VIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `autoread` option in your `.vimrc`? It should force a reload after changes have been made.

From its help page:

```
When a file has been detected to have been changed outside of Vim and
it has not been changed inside of Vim, automatically read it again.
When the file has been deleted this is not done.
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you try use `:edit!`? I think problem is buffer. Vim have buffered file and don't reload it, when you open it via Fuzzy Finder.

Comment: can you please elaborate. I have F3 as a binding for searching files when i load a new file it is loading a version which is probably a week old.

Comment: When you open file and see old content use command `:edit!`. Now file should be reloaded from disk, not from buffer.

Comment: isnt there some option which will prevent caching/buffering? i will not always be sure if the file is changed or not.

Comment: I use NerdTree and when I want open changed file I see prompt (reload file or open from buffer). I will think about it.